# MoviePy, How to add blank left padding to TextClip?

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

I am working on my free time on a project that uses:

- **MoviePy** latest release (1.0.3)
- **ImageMagick** 7.1.0-53
- **Python** >=3.8,<4
- **Windows 10**

My goal is to concatenate clips and for each, I want to show a text at the top left of the screen.

---

```py
textclip: TextClip = TextClip(
   "     " + some_text, # same output with fstring :>5, ljust(5) or (" " * 5) 
   method="caption",
   align="center",
   fontsize=60,
   color="white", 
)
```

I am struggling to add padding to my textclips. I thought I could begin the text with whitespaces but it seems like they are removed even inside the text. The resulting content is sometimes stripped, sometimes splitted in rows.

I was thinking maybe the font is responsible for this ? I don't see any evidence of this issue in the MoviePy TextClip code. Or maybe there is a hacky way to add margin to my texts ??

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: It's not the same question, I encourage you to take a closer look.